# How does Apache thrift fits with Apache hive?

Tags: hive, thrift

Why do Apache Hive needs Apache Thrift? On the Thrift's site it says that it can compile in multiple languages, but I can't understand where does it fits and why do Hive need it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cited [from safaribooksonline](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-hive/9781449326944/ch16.html):

> Chapter 16. Hive Thrift Service
>
> Hive has an optional component known as **HiveServer or HiveThrift that
>   allows access to Hive over a single port**. Thrift is a software
>   framework for scalable cross-language services development. See
>   http://thrift.apache.org/ for more details. Thrift allows clients
>   using languages including Java, C++, Ruby, and many others, **to
>   programmatically access Hive remotely**.
>
> The CLI is the most common way to access Hive. However, the design of
>   the CLI can make it difficult to use programmatically. The CLI is a
>   fat client; it requires a local copy of all the Hive components and
>   configuration as well as a copy of a Hadoop client and its
>   configuration. Additionally, it works as an HDFS client, a MapReduce
>   client, and a JDBC client (to access the metastore). Even with the
>   proper client installation, having all of the correct network access
>   can be difficult, especially across subnets or datacenters.

Couldn't have said it better. Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer

HiveServer is an optional service that allows a remote client to submit requests to Hive, using a variety of programming languages, and retrieve results. HiveServer is built on Apache ThriftTM (http://thrift.apache.org/), therefore it is sometimes called the Thrift server although this can lead to confusion because a newer service named HiveServer2 is also built on Thrift.

For more details on how to connect to hive server(thrift server) see the link above.